# Python regular expressions and CMD

Tags: python, regex, cmd

I'm having some problems with a piece of python work. I have to write a piece of code that is run through CMD. I need it to then open a file the user states and count the number of each alphabetical characters it contains.

So far I have this, which I can run through CDM, and state a file to open. I've messed around with regular expressions, still can't figure out how to count individual characters. Any ideas? sorry if I explained this badly.

```
import sys
import re


filename = raw_input()
count = 0
datafile=open(filename, 'r')
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: No, Im using 'python for rookies' and going through tasks. but I'll keep that in mind for future reference. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stay away from regexes.  They'll be slow and ugly.  Instead, read the entire file into a string, and use the built-in string method `count` to count the characters.

To put it together for you:

```
filename = raw_input()
datafile=open(filename, 'r')
data = datafile.read()
datafile.close() # Don't forget to close the file!
counts = {} # make sure counts is an empty dictionary
data = data.lower() # convert data to lowercase
for k in range(97, 123):  # letters a to z are ASCII codes 97 to 122
    character = chr(k) # get the ASCII character from the number
    counts[character] = data.count(character)
```

Then, you have a dictionary `counts` containing all the counts.  For example, `counts['a']` gives you the number of `a`s in the file.  Or, for the entire list of counts, do `counts.items()`.

Comment: For large files, using the count function will inhibit performance. The entire data set is read for each character being counted.

Comment: Well, as always, the thing to do is actually measure the performance.  And at least with files up to 100MB, the code above runs at least 15 times faster than when using `collections` (on my machine, with python 2.7.2).  That's true either for the entire script, or for just the loops.

Answer (score 3):

The Counter type is useful for counting items. It was added in python 2.7:

```
import collections
counts = collections.Counter()
for line in datafile:
    # remove the EOL and iterate over each character
    #if you desire the counts to be case insensitive, replace line.rstrip() with line.rstrip().lower()
    for c in line.rstrip():
        # Missing items default to 0, so there is no special code for new characters
        counts[c] += 1
```

To see the results:

```
results = [(key, value) for key, value in counts.items() if key.isalpha()]
print results
```

Comment: @TimLesher how does the size of the file come into play?

Comment: I don't think you want to use enumerate there:  enumerate gives you a sequence of (n, k), rather than a sequence of (k, v).

Comment: I was going to suggest a single read and no loop; then I realized it would be clearer as a new answer.

Comment: @TimLesher Good catch. I replaced enumerate with items(), which will return (key, value) as I intended.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is small enough to be read all at once, it's very easy indeed:

```
from collections import Counter

filename = raw_input()
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
counter = Counter(data.lower())

print('\n'.join(str((ch, counter[ch])) for ch in counter if ch.isalpha()))
```

Comment: This is a much better use of the Counter class than @KevinCoffey's.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions, you can do as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]+') # pattern for everything but letters
only_letters = pattern.sub(text, '') # delete everything else
count = len(only_letters) # total number of letters
```

For counting the number of distinct characters, use Counter as already adviced.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are useful if you want to find complex patterns in a string. Because you want to count (as opposed to find) simple (just single alphabetic characters) “patterns”, regular expressions are not the tool of choice here.

If I understand correctly what you are trying, the most transparent way to solve this is to iterate over all lines, and to iterate over all characters in that line, and if that character is alphabetic, add 1 to a corresponding dictionary entry. In code:

```
filename=raw_input()
found = {}

with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        for character in line:
            if character in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz":
            # Checking `in (explicit string)` is not quick, but transparent.
            # You can use something like `character.isalpha()` if you want it to
            # automatically depend on your locale.
                found[character] = found.get(character, 0)+1
                # If there is no dictionary entry for character yet, assume default 0
                # If you need e.g. small and capital letters counted together,
                # "Normalize" them to one particular type, for example using
                # found[character.upper()] = found.get(character, 0)+1
```

After this loop has run through the file, the dictionary `found` will contain the number of occurences for each character.

Comment: The string function isalpha() combined with lower() is simpler than typing out "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"